# Not able to load images using Pkg?

Tags: node.js

So im working on some app that hides to tray once you said so. However when i export it the tray icon doesnt load
The icon is in ./assets/Logo.ico

My Package File:

```
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": "",
    "assets": "assets/*",
    "outputPath": "dist"
  }
```

My code:

```
const ConsoleWindow = require("node-hide-console-window");

const image = require('./assets/Logo.ico');

let Tray = require("ctray");

let tray = new Tray(image); // where the image should be 

tray.tooltip = "Mezo Management RPC"; // Sets the tooltip to display

tray.menu = [ // Sets the tray menu
    "Mezo Management RPC",
    "-",
    {text: "Hide", callback: _ => ConsoleWindow.hideConsole()},
    {text: "Show", callback: _ => ConsoleWindow.showConsole()},

    {text: "Quit", callback: _ => tray.close()}

]

tray.on("close", () => process.exit());
```

Does anyone know how to resolved this issue. If needed this is the source code https://github.com/MezoMgMt/Discord-RPC